# bittorrent - alternating download speed limit for night and day

Tags: windows, bittorrent

I think the question is pretty self-explanatory ... I'm using bittorrent on my windows to download torrent files, and I want to have a low speed limit during the day so I can browse the net faster, but at night I want no capped sp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact steps on how to do this depend completely on the bittorrent client you are choosing to use.  For example, if you were using uTorrent, you would simply go into the preferences, click on Scheduler, click the check box to enable it, and then click the grid square for the time of day on the day you wanted to limit bandwidth, and enter a bandwidth amount in the fields below the grid.

You might want to clarify exactly what BitTorrent client you are using.

But... For BitTorrent and BitComet, the instructions are exactly the same.  For Azureus (Vuze) you need to add the Speed Scheduler plugin.

It will look like this in uTorrent and BitTorrent
[image]

Comment: I think the OP is talking about [BitTorrent](http://www.bittorrent.com/).

Comment: Could be.  But, then he could just be talking about how he is bittorrenting with some other client.  That's why I tried not to assume, but instead address what was there, and provide an example.  But I'll edit to acknowledge that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try a more full-fledged bit torrent client.  In Transmission you can set limits and when they run here:

[image: Transmission Speed Limit Mode screenshot.]